# Hom sets of $G$-linear maps commute with (finite) direct sums

Tags: representation-theory

In a module category, the covariant Hom functors, Hom$(A,-)$, preserve direct sums when the index set is finite.

In the category of representations of a group $G$ over a field $K$, the morphisms are $K$-linear maps which are also $G$-linear. Write Hom${}_K(A,B)^G$. Since there is an *isomorphism* of categories, $F:K[G]-$Mod $\overset{\sim}{\rightarrow}$ Rep${}_K(G)$, I want to say that (assuming the index set is finite) we can apply $F$ to the isomorphism
$$Hom_{K[G]}(A,\bigoplus_i B_i) \cong \bigoplus_i Hom_{K[G]}(A,B_i)$$ 
in $K[G]-$Mod to get an isomorphism in Rep${}_K(G)$:
$$ Hom_{K}(A,\bigoplus_i B_i)^G \cong \bigoplus_i Hom_{K}(A,B_i)^G$$

(Since $F$ is additive, the RHS of the first isomorphism really does map to the RHS of the second.)

However, there is an issue with this reasoning: The Hom sets above may not be objects in their respective categories, only $\mathbb{Z}$-modules. For example, if $A$ is not also a *right* $K[G]$-module, then $Hom_{K[G]}(A,\bigoplus_i B_i)$ is not necessarily a left $K[G]$-module. So, applying $F$ to the first isomorphism doesn't always make sense.

**My goal is to prove the second isomorphism above.**

I've tried proving it directly, via the map $f\mapsto \sum_i p_i f$ where $p_j:\bigoplus_i B_i\rightarrow B_j$ are the natural projections. The problem here is that I can't seem to show that $p_j f\in Hom_K(A, B_j)^G$, so that this map even makes sense. Here's my attempt:

If $\rho, \theta$ are representations of $G$ corresponding to $A, \bigoplus_i B_i$, respectively, then we can define a representation $\theta_j$ of $G$ on $B_j$ by $\theta_j:=p_j \circ\theta \circ i_j$, where $i_j: B_j\rightarrow \bigoplus_i B_i$ is the natural inclusion. With this definition, let's show that $p_j f\in Hom_K(A, B_j)^G$:
$$ \theta_j \circ p_j\circ f =  p_j \circ \theta \circ i_j\circ p_j\circ f$$ 
and 
$$p_j \circ f\circ \rho = p_j \circ \theta\circ f.$$

So it seems that in order for these to be equal, we want $i_j\circ p_j = 1$, which is simply not true.

It seems pretty "obvious" that the second isomorphism is true. (But, obviously not to me!) Again assuming a finite index set, I'm guessing this isomorphism is also true in the other variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don’t get to define $\theta_j$, since $B_j$ is already a represention of $G$.
Currently you’re doing the following:

1. Taking a sum $\bigoplus_i B_i$ of vector spaces $B_i$.
2. Choosing the structure of a $G$-representation on $\bigoplus_i B_i$, named $\theta$.
3. For every $i$, restrict the structure $\theta$ to a the structure of a $G$-representation on $B_i$, named $\theta_i$.
4. Try to show that $\bigoplus_i B_i$ is the direct sum of the $B_i$ as representations.

The problem with this is that we can not necessarily restrict $\theta$ to a $G$-representation on $B_i$.
This works if and only if $B_i$ is a subrepresentation.

Take for example $I = \{1,2\}$, $B_1 = B_2 = K$.
Then $G = \mathbb{Z}/2$ acts on $B_1 \oplus B_2 = K^2$ by switching the coordinates.
But this action can not be restricted to $B_1$ and $B_2$.

This problem is solved by the fact that $\theta$ is defined through the $\theta_j$ (and not vice versa, as attempted above):
If $\theta_j$ is the $G$-representation on $B_j$, then the $G$-representation $\theta$ on $\bigoplus_i B_i$ is (by definition of the direct sum of representations $\bigoplus_i B_i$) given by $\theta = \bigoplus_i \theta_i$.
The inclusions $i_j$ and projections $p_j$ are then homomorphisms of representations, because
$$
    p_j \circ \theta
  = p_j \circ \left( \bigoplus_i \theta_i \right)
  = \theta_j \circ p_j
$$
and similarly $\theta \circ i_j = i_j \circ \theta_j$.
We then get that
$$
    \theta_j \circ p_j \circ f
  = p_j \circ \theta \circ f
  = p_j \circ f \circ \rho.
$$

---

I also want to point out that for an arbitrary index set $J$ we have that
\begin{align*}
          \operatorname{Hom}\left( A, \prod_{j \in J} B_j \right)^G
  \cong   \prod_{j \in J} \operatorname{Hom}(A, B_j)^G,
  \quad   f
  \mapsto (p_j \circ f)_{j \in I}
\end{align*}
and
$$
          \operatorname{Hom}\left( \bigoplus_{j \in J} A_j, B \right)^G
  \cong   \prod_{j \in J} \operatorname{Hom}(A_j, B)^G,
  \quad   f
  \mapsto (f \circ i_j)_{j \in I}
$$
as $K$-vector spaces.
It may actually be more enlightening to check these two isomorphisms, and to check things on elements instead of trying to do everying in a purely abstract way.

Comment: Thank you! On your last comment: So essentially, the standard isomorphisms of Hom sets restrict to isomorphisms on the Hom sets of $G$-homomorphisms. That's nice. 
I do have one concern: When we define the iso, we take $f\in$ Hom$(A, \bigoplus_i B_i)^G$, where $A$ and $\bigoplus_i B_i$ already come equipped with arbitrary $G$ actions, and say where $f$ is sent. But your construction requires a *specific choice* of $G$ action on $\bigoplus_i B_i$ in order to define the iso. So it may need to go the other way: A collection $(g_i)_i$ is sent to $g$ defined by $g(a) = (g_i(a))_i$.

Comment: The sum $\bigoplus_i B_i$ does not mean “some representation which has the underlying vector space $\bigoplus_i B_i$”, but means very specificly “the direct sum of the representations $B_i$ in the category $\mathrm{Rep}_K(G)$” (i.e. their coproduct in this category). So $\bigoplus_i B_i$ already comes with a predefined action (which is induced by the actions on the $B_i$, as described above). We are not free to choose an action on $\bigoplus_i B_i$, but have to use the one given to us by this definition of $\bigoplus_i B_i$. (I reprashed the answer a bit in this regard.)

Comment: Ah I see! The definition/construction of the coproduct in this category has a very specific action that comes with it... Had I been more comfortable with this fact at the outset, I do believe it would have been as “obvious” as it looked :) Thanks again!